# Как присвоить тип в деструктуризации?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Не знаю как присвоить тип к children

```
const RequireAuth = ({children}) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const auth = false; //fake auth

  if (!auth) {
    return <Navigate to='/login' state={{from: location}} />
  }
  return children
}
```

Вот так пробовал, не работает

```
const RequireAuth = ({children: object}) => ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const RequireAuth = ({children}: PropsWithChildren<{}>) => {
```

```
const RequireAuth = ({children}: {children: ТутНужныйТип}) => {
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть как минимум два пути

1. указать тип параметра:

   - `({children}: {children: ChildrenType}) => {`
   - `({children}: ArgType) => {`, где `ArgType` - тип с полем `children`
2. указать тип функции

   ```
   const RequireAuth: ({children:ChildrenType})=>ReturnType = ({children}) => {
   ```

Ввиду того, что используется реакт, можно воспользоваться встроенным типом для функциональных компонентов `FC`